# XAMPP não esta funcionando corretamente

Tags: php, xampp, lado-do-servidor

Olá, quero aprender `php` porém estou com dificuldades em fazer o *XAMPP* funcionar.

Utilizo o `Debian Jessie`, como ainda não tenho muita noção, baixei o `mysql`, `php` e `apache` através de um pacote *(LAMP)*. Porém, agora fui e instalei o *XAMPP*, que imagino que é para o gerenciamento do servidor.

No entanto, quando eu coloco no navegador "localhost" ele me retorna uma página do Apache mostrando aquela mensagem "It Works", porém no tutorial que estou vendo o cara acessa "localhost/xampp" e vai para a tela de gerenciamento dos projetos dele, imagino que o problema esteja no meu *xampp* que não consigo fazer com que os serviços funcionem.

Fica com o *stopped* sempre, e toda vez que clico em *start* não funciona e volta pra *stopped*.

Abaixo imagem de como me mostra a aplicação para ficar mais claro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se vc usa Linux, pra que d!@b0s precisa de *LAMP*?

Comment: olá, acreditei que fosse necessário, mas pelo visto não é ? Por favor pode me explicar, rs, pelo oque havia entendido eu preciso instalar LAMP para ter acesso a phpmyadmin certo ? ou não ?

Comment: Não, não precisa. o `PHPMyAdmin` é outro programa. Todos eles (Apache, PHP, MySQL) são aplicações independentes.

Comment: Como você pode ver nessa imagem que postou, o *LAMP* é só um tipo de interface gráfica pra vc "controlar" os serviços. Quando acontece algo errado (como agora) vc tem que olhar os logs e investigar pra descobrir o motivo da falha. Tradução: aprenda a gerenciar os serviços sem o *LAMP*. É melhor.

Comment: Não posso te garantir Leo, mas pode ser que você tenha dois servidores instalados. Um apontando para o var/www/html/ e outro para a pasta do LAMP. Eu não recomendo o Debian para quem não está ainda costumado com servidores. Ubuntu e outras distros mais populares podem servir melhor ao ambiente de aprendizado. Sempre trabalhe se acostumando a dar permissões de pasta pelo CHMOD. Para instalação mais detalhada de pacotes, sem grandes problemas, use o synaptic.

Comment: @PauloSérgioDuff, não tem como deduzir isso da imagem que ele postou... Na verdade, não dá pra deduzir muito. De fato, só podemos ver que FTP roda, mas que Mysql e Apache não...

Comment: Olá @PauloSérgioDuff, bom identifiquei a pasta var/www/html de quando eu instalei o LAMP porém não encontrei a pasta htdocs do XAMPP, acho que o problema começa ai, obrigado.

Comment: Não deduzi da imagem. Mas muitas vezes o iniciante faz várias tentativas diferentes para iniciar o servidor. Se estiver usando a mesma porta não vai rolar. Melhor ele fazer do jeito B-A-BA eu acho.

Comment: Então está usando provavelmente somente a interface do LAMP. O que estou achando estranho, é que a pasta htdocs geralmente é do windows. Não me lembro se no linux ela tem o mesmo nome, acho que não.

Comment: O padrão no Linux é `/var/www/html` nas versões mais novas do `Apache`. Esse **é** o seu `htdocs`, ou `root directory`.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta iniciar o apache e o mysql manualmente, rode os comandos abaixo no terminal como root:

**Apache:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

**Mysql:**

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Provavelmente vai retornar algum erro, copia e cola aqui.